# What is this symbol called?

Tags: notation

Not much to this question, just can't find the name.

I cannot find what this symbol is called, its like a n with a tail before it.
It is something to do with eigenvectors in my context.

Purpose is I need to put it in LaTeX.

[image: weird n with a curve before it]

Comment: It's the Greek eta.

Comment: The greek letter *eta* $\eta$.

Comment: In LaTeX it is given by `\eta`. FYI see [here](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/symbols/greek-alphabet/).

Comment: If you're looking for $\TeX$ commands for symbols, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) lets you draw and it will try to guess the symbol.

Comment: @Arthur this has been added to my favorites, so useful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are refering to

> $$\large\eta$$

which is the greek letter "eta".

Comment: That's the one thanks.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Happy to help. In this case you could just accept the answer if you are satisfied :)

Comment: Have to wait 9 mins, I will accept when I am able to :)

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Okay. to add some more context: the letter "eta" $\eta$ aswell as the letter "lambda" $\lambda$ are commonly used to denote eigenvectors and eigenvalues respectively.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden I was informed about your edit (which already got rejected) and I would like to explain why I decided to not add those details: I guess it is enough that Dexexify is linked within the comments (as done by *Arthur*) and moreover the main purpose of your question was to determine what this specific symbal is called; not to ask for a way of determining it in general (which would have been off-topic here). So, I would leave it in the comment section alone.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much for explaining, my reasoning was I read the comments section is not the place to leave valuable information. But yes I agree, the information should be an answer to a different, more general question :)

Comment: @HectorHaffenden No problem. A slight side note: I guess you tried to repay my help by upvoting almost all of my answers/questions; however, serial upvoting (or downvoting) results in an automatical ["vote correcting"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) done by the system, i.e. some of the votes are getting reversed.

Comment: Noted. Didn't know that's how the system sees it. Sorry for the fuss. To explain: your extra step at explaining indicated you could be a valuable source of information, on maths and mainly how to answer a question and explain a complex topic. I opened up all your answers, read them (I admit briefly) and up-voted the ones I found valuable open. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden No need for apologies. I didn't know it for myself for a long time and only heard stories that this could happen in connection with serial votings. However, I appreciate your compliment as you would determine my posts as valuable and you surely can upvote them; but maybe not all at once ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in your post it is
$$
\hat{\eta}_A.
$$
The greek letter is $\eta$.